# Redirect view with Html.ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, controller, html.actionlink

I have the following problem:
I make the call to the method of a controller, it receives a parameter.
The code is as follows:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Preview", "ReportExecution", "Report", new { reportName = ViewBag.docLiquidation }, null)
```

This generates me the following address:

```
http://localhost:65500/Report/ReportExecution/docRetentionDeclaration
```

docRetentionDeclaration identified as a parameter, but does not.

The code of the method is as follows:

```
[HttpPost]
public FileResult ReportExecution(string reportName)
{
     .
     .
     return new File();
}
```

I appreciate the help you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the following route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{reportName}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", reportName = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

the controller action will expect the parameter to be called reportName:

```
public ActionResult ReportExecution(string reportName)
{
    ...
}
```

Notice how the parameter name of the controller action must match the route token in your route definition.

Comment: Sure, the name of the parameter corresponds to the route.             [HttpPost]
public FileResult ReportExecution(string reportName)

Comment: `[HttpPost]`???? And how do you expect to invoke a method that accepts only the POST verb with an anchor?